# Ruby - writing a method without a "parameter"

Tags: ruby

For example, the array class has a method named ".sort" that you call on an array with the following syntax:

```
[2, 3, 4, 1].sort
```

From my limited knowledge, I only know how to write methods that take an actual parameter:

```
def sort(array)
   ...
end
```

and are called as such:

```
sort([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

How would you go about setting up a method that can be called with the dot notation (please correct me if I'm wrong) syntax?

*To clarify, I'm trying to add a method into the existing class Array that can remove duplicate objects. I know the ".uniq" method already does that, but I'm re-writing it for the purpose of learning how its done. I only know how to write the method as such:

```
def my_uniq(array)
   ...
end
```

where the array is the parameter that I can work with inside my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start thinking in terms of sending messages to object.  i.e. Instead of seeing them as calling methods, see them as `sending message to object(s)`.  When you do send messages, the object would check if it can fulfill the request (ie. check if there is a method by that name exists in here or in its parent) if so it does.  So in essence, the `sort` is a message (method) to `array` object.

```
class Array
  def sort
    # do sorting
  end

  # example taken from @codycaughlan 
  # allows you to send message `hi` to your array object
  def hi
    "Hi, #{length}"
  end
end

# so instead of calling method hi([2,9,0]) 
# send hi message to an array object

[2,9,0].hi

# instead of calling method sort([2,9,0])
# send sort message to an array object

[2,9,0].sort
```

**Update**

Let us say you want to write a method that works on an array that prints `*` multiplied by the number you pass.

```
class Array
  def print_stars
    self.each { |i| puts "*" * i}
  end
end

# now let us send a message / call
[1,2,3].print_stars #=> this should produce

*
**
***
```

As you may already know, these messages can be chained. For e.g.

```
[1,2,3].reverse.print_stars  #=> produces

***
**
*
```

Comment: How would I go about "playing" with the array object that I'm sending a message to though. For example, with the method I'm "monkey-patching" to class Array, I would typically take the parameter array, iterate through the array with .each, if element already exists, delete... etc.. How would I write my def to access this array is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @user2684075 Inside a method you reference the receiver using the keyword `self`.

Comment: Or should I say, there is a variable associated with the parameter. What "variable" would I type in the method I'm creating to work with the receiver, or the object I'm sending messages to?

Comment: In most cases `self` is redundant, i.e. you can just write `each` instead of `self.each`, just keep in mind that you are sending `each` to `self`, i.e. your array instance.

Comment: @Stefan: That's correct. `self` was included for clarity of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the "argument" is. In your example of:

`[2, 3, 4, 1].sort`

The argument is an instance of `Array`. You could monkey-patch `Array` to add a method of your choosing:

```
class Array
  def hi
    "Hi, #{length}"
  end
end

puts [1,2,3].hi

=> Hi, 3
```

Comment: The receiver is usually not called argument.